# droidText for pdf generation on android

Tags: android, pdf-generation, android-droidtext

I am looking into using droidText which is apparently a version of iText specifically for android.  But i can't find any tutorials?  has anyone used it? can you point me towards any tutorials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>I just revamped the droidText project site as there wasn't much documentation to begin with. To see how you can get started check out the new wiki page here: http://code.google.com/p/droidtext/wiki/GettingStarted</strike>

Contact me if you have any more problems/questions

droidText has been shut down and is no longer maintained

Comment: How to contact you if I have questions? The site seems to be down?

Comment: droidText has been shut down and is no longer maintained

Comment: @kungjohan if you still need a PDF library for Android: iTextG is the official Android port of iText: http://developers.itextpdf.com/itextg-android

Answer (score 1):

^

1. That’s an error.

Your client does not have permission to get URL /p/droidtext/wiki/GettingStarted from this server

Comment: Do you have any idea why is that? I can not access droidText site either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same code which is used in iText you can download the pdf [here](http://code.google.com/p/agilepractice/downloads/detail?name=iText%20in%20Action.pdf&can=2&q=)